# $_GET doesnt retrieve the id from URL

Tags: php

I have a vertical menu bar that has categories and these categories have products under them. The URL seen when I hover over the category is `..../index.php?catid=1`

For instance I have

```
category- SCHOOLS (catid=1)
products - NPS, DPS...
```

In order to display the products, I need to use *$_GET* to get the 'catid' from the URL when I hover over the product.

This is the code for that part:

```
$fetchedcatid = $_GET['catid'];
$resultLIst = array();
$i = 0;
$sql="Select * from product_master where id = ".$fetchedcatid;
$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

This gives me a MYSQL error since the catid is not stored in $fetchedcatid.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: On reading your question more closely...do you need to get the catid when you hover, or when you click that link? If you click a link with a query string (the ?catid=1 part) PHP will/should get it, but your use of "hover" makes me think javascript is involved.

Comment: I need it when i hover..so it cant be done without javascript?

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Oh, so you do need it when you hover! Your problem isn't with PHP or the web server, it's that hovering over a link doesn't send a request to the server at all, and thus no variables in _GET until you click. That just won't work without javascript - or until you click :) If you need help post a new question specifically about what you are trying to accomplish, including html (or ideally a jsfiddle).

Answer (score 2):

you need check first that `catid` is set before use also use of singleton is also not good option

```
if(isset($_GET['catid'])){
 // other stuff use $_GET['catid']

}
```

you can also use [`is_int`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) or [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to make sure that id have only digit

---

### **Warning**

your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape all `get`, `post` and `request` and the better approach will be using [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. [**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a test on the `$_GET['catid']` variable

```
$fetchedcatid = isset($_GET['catid']) ? $_GET['catid'] : FALSE;

if($fetchedcatid) { 
  // do stuff here 
  // you will want to sanitize this variable especially when using it in a mysql_query statement
 //For Example:

$resultLIst = array();
$i          = 0;
$sql        = "Select * from product_master where id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($fetchedcatid);
$query      = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: this will throw a notice, must use isset()

Comment: @Galen Yes just realized that and edited it.

Comment: fyi you can also make it safe by validating that id is numeric ..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are having a problem with the $_GET variables, not whether or not they are set (while all good points, I don't think that's the main problem the OP has).

Try:

```
<?php 

if(empty($_GET)) 
echo "_GET is empty"; 
else 
print_r($_GET); 

?>
```

If you aren't getting any variables then there is a problem with your configuration settings, perhaps _GET is disabled or is being reassigned to some other variable by a framework?

[PHP Documentation for GET, POST, and REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: I think its very likely that _GET is disabled...because Ive tried the stuff above! Any idea how I can change that?

Comment: It appears to be a configuration problem on your system. Assuming you aren't using a front-controller of programming framework, the most common cause of this is incorrect URL rewriting (through Apache/.htaccess, etc). Try  XAMPP (portable or installed) and see if your code works or not. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html